# Change permalink structure only for particular page - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I want to create a page with a path like this:

`http://www.website.it/it/azienda/chi-siamo.html`

My current website is like this:

`http://www.website.it/chi-siamo.html`

I added the **.html** with the html in url plugin ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/html-in-url/#installation )

How can I add the - **/azienda/** chi-siamo.html, **but only for that page**.

A different page needs to be:
`http://www.website.it/it/multigallery/gallery/index/galleryid/1/realizzazioni.html/`

while I have:

`http://website.it/multigallery.html`

Is this even possible ?

Note: I am using the Jupiter Theme and I have Polylang installed (2 languages active)

Answer (score 0):

Create a page with the slug `azienda` and then make the `chi-siamo` page a child of it.

You might be able to achieve the other URL with some custom [rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).